# Which directory in my plugin repo does Wordpress Plugin Directory package?

Tags: plugin-development, repository

I am a little confused about that. If I want tags/1.2.3 to be available for download instead of the one in trunk, how do I do that? In the FAQ, it says that I should change stable tag to 1.2.3 in trunk/readme.txt. I did that but WPD is still showing the old version in the trunk. I thought it would automatically package tags/1.2.3 after changing stable tag in trunk/readme.txt. Or I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to commit  the changes to the /trunk directory yourself, changing the version number in the /trunk/readme.txt is not going to do this on its own.

### Update

Whenever i update a version say from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 i first create a directory in /tags
and name it just like the last version 1.0.0
the i copy everything from /trunk to it so if someone wants an older version he can get it.
the i just commit any changes of the new version to /trunk

so basically trunk holds only the latest version (no need to create a new directory in trunk.)

Comment: Oh I see. How do I do that? Editing files in both directory (trunk and tags/1.2.3) would be a too daunting. There must be something I am missing. I guess `svn cp` won't cut it because I tried it before and my trunk got messed up.

Comment: When i upadte a version i create a directory inside /tags named as the last version and copy everything from trunk to that, only then i update the trunk directory with the new version.

Comment: So if I update the trunk I would just: `svn cp tags/newversion/* trunk/` and then `svn commit -m "Updated trunk"` right?

Comment: i updated the answer to explain better

Comment: Yah, I got that completely. But the part where you say *commit any changes of the new version to /trunk* is not clear to me. Is there a particular command for that? Or I could just use `cp`? Thanks for the patience!